# Add Apple Developer Account in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, mobile-development, apple-developer-account

I've tried to add an Apple Developer Account in Visual Studio 2017 but when I go **Tools/Options/Xamarin/Apple Accounts**, the Add button is disabled:

[Xamarin options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p54d.png)

I have tried to update but still isn't working (Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.9.29), besides I have a Mac paired already by IP

Comment: Xamarin is no longer supporting VS2017, so the tooling is not up to date

Comment: One piece of constructive criticism? This showed up on my "radar" only because you tagged this as [ios]. Why? Some questions really shouldn't be tagged with the maximum of 5 subjects. This sounds like [xamarin] only - target your questions and you probably will get a much better response.

Answer (score 0):

You VS could do that. Apple account management is available on Visual Studio for Mac, Visual Studio 2019, and `Visual Studio 2017 (Version 15.7 and higher)`.

You must also have a paid Apple Developer account to use this feature. Before you begin, be sure to first accept any user license agreements in the Apple Developer portal.

You could check the requirements and steps on MS docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/apple-account-management?tabs=windows#add-an-apple-developer-account